# How to implement analytics for facebook like?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

is there a way , I can track  facebook like   with help of event tracking in google analystics 
ie. i want to use 
ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav buttons', 4) ant not this code : ga('send', 'social', 'facebook', 'like', 'http://mycoolpage.com');

Comment: Doesn't facebook api give you a js event for like/unlike? You should be able to use that and track using UA anyway you want

Comment: yes facebook provide api to handle that .  I have posted teh solution that i h ave used in my page.

Answer (score 1):

Ok ..this is how we can implement Google analystics in facebook

1) Facebook like is added via its social plugin and Facebook provide events to handle like button 
for this put code like this in your jsp page .

2) Facebook provide window.fbAsyncInit method and any event provided by Facebook can be written into it .
3) more information can be obtained from

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',function(href,widget) {

    ga('send', 'social', 'facebook', 'like', 'your facebook page link');

        });

        };

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                            (function(d, s, id) {
                                 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                                 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                                 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                                 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&#38;appId=0000000000000";
                                 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                                 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

                </script>

    <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        data-width="450" data-height="590" data-show-faces="true"
        data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am unable to inspect the "Like" button as I can't find it (assuming your site is mycoolpage.com), but  you can do something like this, by attaching an onclick handler:

```
<a href="/some/path/to/like/button.html" onclick="ga('send','event','button','click','nav buttons', 4);">Facebook Like!</a>
```

Comment: actully what your code does , it will track when user clik on facebook like button , not when the user actuuly like the page.i have posted the answer which i have implemented in my site .

Comment: Your question is misleading as you asked to track fb likes with events and you specifically indicated that you want to use the event method and not the social method. You should clarify your question next time.